# How can I know if the connection to an existing database Neo4j has been successful?

Tags: django, neo4j, django-forms

I am newbie in python / django. Using neo4django library and an existing Neo4j database I would like to connect to it and test if the connection is successful. How can I achieve this behavior?

Answer (score 0):

You don't 'connect' to a database anymore. This is the Frameworks job. You just define the [parameters](http://neo4django.readthedocs.org/en/latest/getting-started.html) and start writing Models.
Those Models are your entities with fields which can be used like a variable. In other words: your models are your definition of the Database tables.

Answer (score 0):

You can test against http://host:7474/db/data/ if it returns a 200, Ok.

Comment: Would you mind showing an ex of doing this programmatically via Python?

Answer (score 0):

I don't know much about neo4django, but you can  test if a database is accessible with py2neo, the general purpose Python driver (http://py2neo.org/2.0/).

One simple way is to ask the server for its version:

```
from py2neo import Graph
from py2neo.packages.httpstream import SocketError

# adjust as necessary
graph = Graph("http://localhost:7474/db/data/")

try:
    print(graph.neo4j_version)
except SocketError:
    print('No connection to database.')
```